# How do I automatically save results of a table in a JMeter Listener at the end of the test

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a Listener element that calculates some results from samples executed. I can manually save these results at the end of the test, but i would like to save them at the end of the test automatically to a file.

What do i need to do reacte to the End of test notification that seems to be sent by the JMeterEngine? Or is there a better solution do something at the end of the test?

Comment: How your results are stored? show more details

Comment: The results are stored in a JTable element. The saving of the data itself is not the problem. The Listener has a Button for triggering that manually.
But what i am l am looking for is to do the same thing automatically at the end of the test, so i don't have to do it manually any more.

Answer (score 0):

In listeners there is a section named Filename just mention the path with the filename extension in which you want to save the result set, In this way J Meter will automatically saves the results that you want to store at the end of the test execution.

[image: listener image]

Comment: yea, but that just saves the single sample results, and not the table that is created from them in the listener.

Comment: Which listener you are using?

Comment: I am extending the AbstractGraphPanelVisualizer

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)

1. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
2. Install JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool
3. Install [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/)
4. [Run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
5. Generate textual representation of the [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) table like:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv my-table.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```
6. That's it, now you can open `my-table.csv` and enjoy your test results

You can generate other reports and charts similarly, check out [How to Use the JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/) article for more details.